# How to use ColorPicker from Lars Werkman

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, dialog

i wanted to use the HoloColorPicker of LarsWerkman (https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker).

But i don't know how to import this in my Project, i tried it a long of time, but i didn't found a solution.
I tried to:

- Create an extra Package
- Import the Javafiles in my existing Package
- Import the XML-Files in my Project.

But nothing worked.
I hope somebody can help me, cause i'm working at least 5h to import this (I'm an Androidprogramming beginner!)

Lucas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Android Studio then it is simpler than you may think, just add

```
compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.4'
```

to your `dependencies` block in app\build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you have tried already but you are trying to do is called Library Project.

What you will have to do is import the `HoloColorPicker` into eclipse as a standalone project, either by downloading the code or using Git. then you need to mark it as a [library project](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html#tutorial_library_flag). Once that is done, you want to import that [library into your project](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html#tutorial_library_usage) (as a library, not jar).

After that you can start using `HoloColorPicker` in the same way that is explained in the GitHub page.